# 'The program can’t start because libmysql.dll is missing from your computer’ BUT it IS there?

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, dll

The program needs libmysql.dll It is there under c:\xampp\mysql\lib along with libmysql.lib. In the visual c++ settings I have libmysql.lib added to Linker->Input and I have c:\xampp\mysql\lib added to Linker->Additional Library Directories.

Yet I still get the same error. I've reinstalled xampp. I've copied the dlls to system32 directory. Same error though.

Answer (score 2):

Try copying libmysql.dll into the same folder as your executable. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try download libmysql.dll and drop in same folder on your program